# How to prevent spelling mistakes in TestNG groups?

Tags: eclipse, testing, testng

We have just started to use TestNG to implement our tests. Now we have defined four groups to arrange our tests (i.e GroupA, GroupB, GroupC and GroupD).

**Is there a possibility in TestNG to prevent spelling mistakes by using these groups?**

```
@Test(groups = {"GroupA", "GoupB"})
```

How can we advice a developer of the spelling mistake in "GroupB" (missing r) ? Also a possibility to just allow predefined names for groups would be OK.

One idea was do define code templates, which could be included to Eclipse via template.xml. But this seems not to be developer-friendly.

Any other idea would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use constants...

You can have dedicated class with constants like:

```
public class TestType {
    private static final String GROUP_A = "GroupA";
    private static final String GROUP_B = "GroupB"

    /**
     * Avoid instantiation
     */
    private TestType() {
    }
}
```

and than:

```
 @Test(groups = {TestType.GROUP_B, TestType.GROUP_A})
```

This works for us fine.
The only small problem (if you are using Maven) is that you have to have such class in each separate project or extract it into some common testing Jar. Because Maven doesn't allow to share test dependencies by default.
(I am aware of posibility to share test jars between projects with special maven patched plugin, but wouldn't go that path once again.)

Promote using these constants during core reviews.

BTW, missed test should come up in lower test coverage ratio.

Comment: Thanks Ikrnac for your response,
we have started with this solutions and will see, if this works for all developers. If not we will use the suggested way from Bhupesh.
Thanks both. I will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use IAnnotationTransformer inteface . Override transform method by setGroups method in ITestAnnotation object. Maintain the group outside 
    somewhere in config , xml , csv or any other file . This is the only way what I think. Because @Test annonation can changed only by IAnnotationTransformer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
Am I right, that IAnnotationTransformer and ITestAnnotation are interface in TestNG development? So you mean to change the TestNG implementation?
We hoped to find a way to use the existing TestNG-tools, but otherwise we will give it a try.

Comment: You don't need to change souece code, just need to implement these interface, because as per testng doc this is the only solution for it