# Prevent TestNG hard coded group name

Tags: java, testng

The group names of `TestNG` are often been hard coded and may decrease the quality of software. I wonder how can I prevent hard coded group names.

In TestCase.java, yes I can use a static final String instead, like @JavaSoftwareTester asked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26732546/5441945).

```
public class TestType {
    private static final String GROUP_A = "GroupA";
    private static final String GROUP_B = "GroupB"

    /**
     * Avoid instantiation
     */
    private TestType() {
    }
}
```

However, it seems this final String cannot be used in the testNG.xml, like:

```
<groups>
    <run>
        <!-- I don't want hard coded -->
        <include name = "GroupA" />
        <!-- but this is incorrect -->
        <include name = TestType.GROUP_A />
    </run>
</groups>
```

Summary: I want to prevent hard coded group names but I cannot find the appropriate mechanism. Please kindly show how this issue could be solved.

Comment: Xml is text and not code, so it is not possible to reference java code in a xml description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `Beanshell` support that TestNG provides.

Here's how you go about doing it.

- First add a dependency to the beanshell library by adding the contents from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache-extras.beanshell/bsh/2.0b6) (This is required because TestNG brings in the beanshell libraries only as an optional dependency)
- You then define a beanshell as shown below to be your method selector

`<method-selector>
<script language="beanshell">
    <![CDATA[
            import org.rationale.emotions.stackoverflow.qn45272885.TestClass;
            groups.containsKey(TestClass.GROUP_B);
]]>
</method-selector>`

Don't forget to make the constants as public in your class `TestType`.

To learn more about Beanshell integration with TestNG you can refer to my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/) and also the official TestNG documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell)